# Why does Sinestro have The Guardians create a ring of fear?

Tags: plot-explanation, green-lantern

In the movie [*Green Lantern*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1133985/), if fear is the very thing that turned the original Guardian into Parallax, and it cannot be conquered (The Guardians themselves say so)... why then does Sinestro decide to have The Guardians create a ring of fear? If the Lanterns fought Parallax with fear... would he not just feed off of the fear from the ring? Not to mention, wouldn't the fear take control of any Lantern that tries to master it within the yellow ring? (Example: Sinestro in the end credits.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sinestro, was the leader of the Green Lantern Corps at the time and regarded to be one of the greatest Green Lanterns ever. He also had a very big ego and believed that he could accomplish what Parallax had failed to do: control the yellow essence of fear without losing himself to it. He also believed that the green essence of will power was no match for the yellow, and that if he wanted to defeat Parallax he would have to use the same power, which is why he asked for a yellow ring to be constructed.

Had Sinestro's plan prevailed, he would've worn the yellow ring into battle with Parallax. The latter wouldn't be able to siphon fear from Sinestro's ring because the yellow ring didn't *emit* fear, it *absorbed* it, the same way Parallax does.

Comment: Something to remember is that Sinestro turns out to be Hal's arch enemy, as we know from the Comic books. There needed to be an avenue or device to show us how that happens and for a lead in for a sequel to this movie. We needed to know *how does Sinestro end up being bad* especially considering having seen him as the leader of the Lantern Corps.

Comment: I understand Sinestro's arrogance being the largest factor behind creating the ring, but, why would The Guardians agree to create it when they must know of the possible consequences? If they are supposed to be all knowing shouldn't they be wiser than this, and at least try to steer Sinestro away from the idea?

Comment: @Stephen_Film_Guy - It's not really expanded on in the movie, but I guess they have blind faith in him?